# jQuery Mobile dialog BLANK

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I've been searching for a solution on the internet but I didn't find any.
In my jQuery Mobile application, I have multiple HTML files each one representing a page to keep the workflow clean, therefore I use AJAX for navigation.
I have a button on a map in my page `fleet.html` (3rd in navigation) that opens a dialog, the opening process is done with **javascript**, only when I click on the button it shows me a **blank** dialog with no text and no buttons in it.
Here's `fleet.html` :

```
<div data-role="page" id="fleetPage" class="no-bg">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Flotte</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="map-container">
            <div id="fleet-map"></div>
        </div><!-- END map-container -->
    </div><!-- END content -->

    <div data-role="dialog" id="deviceInfoDialog" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h3>Informations</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>POI Infos</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</div><!-- END page -->
```

And here's how I open the dialog :

```
function onSelectFeature() {
    $("#fleetPage #deviceInfoDialog").dialog();
    $.mobile.changePage($("#fleetPage #deviceInfoDialog"), {
        transition: "slidedown"
    });
}
```

Comment: Which version are you using??

Comment: jQuery Mobile 1.3.1 - jQuery 1.10.2

Answer (score 1):

Move your dialog div outside of the page div.  Add a hidden link that when clicked would open the dialog.  Rework your script function to emulate that link getting clicked.

I tested this and it works fine:

```
<div data-role="page" id="fleetPage" class="no-bg">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Flotte</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="map-container">
            <div id="fleet-map"> <a href="javascript: onSelectFeature();">onSelectFeature</a></div>
        </div><!-- END map-container -->
    </div><!-- END content -->


    <script>
        function onSelectFeature() {
            $("#lnkDeviceInfoDialog").click();
        }
    </script>

    <a id='lnkDeviceInfoDialog' href="#deviceInfoDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slidedown" style='display:none;'></a>


</div><!-- END page -->

<div data-role="dialog" id="deviceInfoDialog" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h3>Informations</h3>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p>POI Infos</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think that is key to move the dialog or page out of the main page.  I was making the same mistake, I was thinking since a dialog and a page were not the same they could live inside of each other, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function onSelectFeature() {
    $.mobile.changePage( "#deviceInfoDialog", { role: "dialog", transition: "slidedown" } );
}
```

And your html should be like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="fleetPage" class="no-bg">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
        <h1>Flotte</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" data-theme="a">
        <div class="map-container">
            <div id="fleet-map"></div>
        </div><!-- END map-container -->
    </div><!-- END content -->
</div><!-- END page -->

    <div data-role="dialog" id="deviceInfoDialog" data-theme="b" data-close-btn="right">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h3>Informations</h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>POI Infos</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Check my update. I believe your dialog should be outside the main page. It's like a multipage html.

Comment: Please provide a jsfidle